# how can i display 4 images on cells in each row on collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

how can i display 4 cells in each row for example (i have `collectionView` have 10 rows, each row have 4 cells for different screens for all devices)on `collectionView` for each device because i display (4 images for iPhone5 )and (for iPhone 6 is display 5 images )and (iPhone 6 plus it display 6 images )on cells i need to make all these different screens display 4 cells in each row in `collectionView`.

thanks Advance

Comment: sounds like you really want a table view, or to change the cell size on different devices

Comment: like @Wain said, tableView or count cell sizes for every screen, make some custom cell styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your size like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let minSpace: CGFloat = 10
    return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width - minSpace)/4, YourCellHeight)
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate Happy Coding :)

Comment: Nirav D sir how can i show a full image in left hand side and two half half image in right hand side?